# Extract month and year from mongodb Datetime filed and Group_by in Django

Tags: python, django, mongodb, date, group-by

im using monogengine in my Django project and i want count() number of jobs in each year and each month. 
after each time users do some jobs, it will insert and save in my Database nicely. now i want to count them and use this number later in some charts in year-month format.

this is my model

```
from mongoengine import Document, EmbeddedDocument, fields

class PortModel(EmbeddedDocument):
    idx=fields.StringField()
    protocolname=fields.StringField()
    protocolnumber=fields.StringField()
    description=fields.StringField(required=False, blank=True)

class PortScanModel(Document):
    date=fields.DateTimeField()
    host=fields.StringField()
    ip=fields.StringField()
    Ports=fields.ListField(fields.EmbeddedDocumentField(PortModel))
```

i want something like group_by just on year and month for counting rows and extract how much users used it.
my Date field is something like '2019-12-02T19:47:31.847170' and i want something like below:

```
year-month | number of rows
---------------------------
2018-01    | 2
2018-02    | 7
2019-01    | 3
2019-05    | 14
```

i searched a lot for extracting year and month from date, but nothing i found.
i don't know can i Extracting and Grouping in one Command or not in mongo, but it wasn't hard in SQL.

*thanks for your helps.*

Comment: Have you tried [**`ExtractMonth`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.ExtractMonth) DB function?

Comment: @JPG annotate dosen't work with monoengine in django, but thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a long time searching, i found the answer and i want to share it with others.
in my situation i should use *aggregate()* to extract year and month from dateTime field and then group on them [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/).

```
$month --> extract month from date
$year  --> extract year from date
$group --> group_by command
$sum   --> for counting something (here +1)
```

so, i changed my query like below:

```
    pipeline = [
    {
        "$group":{
            "_id":{
                "year": {"$year": "$date"},
                "month":{"$month":"$date"}
                },
                "total": { "$sum": 1 }
                }
    }]
```

and my python Query is like this:

```
PortScanModel.objects.aggregate(*pipeline)
```

**Finish!** this command first extract year and month from date then group_by year and month and counts the rows. now i have the count of them per year-month and i can plot a chart of usage.